# Find out the length of a String

Tags: cobol

Suppose I have a variable `PIC X(20)`.

The variable contains some value e.g. `ABC WXYZ`.

How to find out the length of the string excluding the space in between?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If nothing, you should at least search this site as string processing has come up a few times and there are ideas there to get you started. Then if you get stuck, you can ask a better, more specific question.

Comment: @Maxcc0 Does the provided answer work for you? If yes: please mark it as answer, if no: please comment on the answer what you miss.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really sure that you don't want the space in between you can define test-val and use this in `PERFORM`:

```
   77  some-len   PIC 9(02). *> make sure to use appropriate length, if "big" use COMP-5
   77  string-ptr PIC 9(02). *> make sure to use appropriate length
   77  some-var   PIC X(20) VALUE '  ABC WXYZ'.
   77  var-len    PIC 9(02) VALUE LENGTH OF some-var.
   01  test-char  PIC X.
       88 no-spaces  values 'A' THROUGH 'Z'
                            'a' THROUGH 'z'
                            '0' THROUGH '9'
                            '-', '.'.  

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

       MOVE 0 TO some-len
       PERFORM VARYING string-ptr FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL   string-ptr > var-len
          MOVE some-var (string-ptr) TO test-char
          IF no-spaces ADD 1 TO some-len END-IF
       END-PERFORM
```

As Bill pointed out if you ONLY want to know the "not spaces" characters there's a faster option that needs less vars (make sure you comment this letting you and others know what this does:

```
  *> set numbers of all non-spaces in some-len
       MOVE 0 TO some-len
       INSPECT some-var TALLYING some-len FOR ALL SPACES
  *> add more counts here if you want to remove more chars like x'0D'/x'0A'/x'00', ...
  *>   INSPECT some-var TALLYING some-len FOR ALL x'00'
  *>   INSPECT some-var TALLYING some-len FOR ALL x'0D'
  *>   INSPECT some-var TALLYING some-len FOR ALL x'0A'
  *> and finally subtract it from the fields length
       SUBTRACT some-len FROM LENGTH OF some-var GIVING some-len
  *>
```

Comment: For information, the username Maxcc0 hints and Mainframe, and indeed a quick look at their profile reveals a Mainframe tag. And of course remembering their previous question. So 78 won't work. COMP-5 would be bad if not needed (it isn't here). Why not just count the spaces? INSPECT ... TALLYING for instance.

Comment: @BillWoodger:
The information of Maxcc0 user profile is not part of the question :-)

I've changed the source to use the `LENGTH OF` special register instead of level 78 extension and added the INSPECT option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. INSPECT will work fine :) .

Comment: @Maxcc0 OK, please mark this as answer then (click on the check mark)